# If $f(x) = x^2+3x-5$ and $g(x) = 2x -3$, find $x$

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

If $f(x) = x^2+3x-5$ and $g(x) = 2x -3$, find $x$.

According to the textbook, the solutions are  $x = 1$ or $x=-2$

Here is the textbook question:

[image: Trying to solve f]

I would appreciate it if you could post the solution in a step by step form.

Thank You

Comment: Find $x$ so that $f(x)=g(x)$... or something else?

Comment: I tried a few different things to find x but I was unable to find the value of x.

Comment: I'm asking what are the directions?

Comment: @SIDDHARTHVADER I found $x=42$. If that doesn't work for you, then  clarify why not.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Direction?

Comment: Instructions, directions, whatever words told you exactly what to do here....

Comment: @SIDDHARTHVADER The question as posted doesn't make sense; there is something missing.

Comment: Based on your text book answers, it is very possible the instructions might have been "Find $x$ so that $f(x)=g(x)$"

Comment: I edited my post and added a screenshot of the question
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRYEx.png

Comment: @SIDDHARTHVADER : So you are asking about part f, where the full directions are "determine $x$ when $f(x) = g(x)$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you said the answer is $x=1$, $x=-2. \space$ I assume you mean $f(x)=g(x)$.

> $$
> x^2+3x−5 = 2x-3
> $$
>   $$
> x^2+x−2 = 0
> $$
>   $$
> (x-1)(x+2)=0
> $$
>   $$
> x-1=0 \space or \space x+2=0
> $$
>   $$
> x=1 \space or \space x=-2
> $$

Comment: PERFECT!!! I did not notice that I did not say f(x) = g(x)...my bad. Really stressed about test tomorrow.

Comment: @SIDDHARTHVADER all good, good luck with your test!